How to programmatically wrap an output expression in a function
When I execute:
Audio["ExampleData/rule30.wav"]

I get an Audio Object.

How can I programmatically wrap the output in another function (without evaluating it). Concretely, I want to wrap the Audio Object with the AudioPlay function so that it looks like this:

So I am looking to write a function f that takes as input the Audio and outputs the desired output wrapped in the AudioPlay function and unevaluated.
Input:
f[Audio["ExampleData/rule30.wav"]]

Output:


I believe you are looking for Defer.
f[a_] := Defer[AudioPlay[a]]
f[Audio["ExampleData/rule30.wav"]]



Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. Unfortunately, it causes M14 to crash on my Mac.

It would help to understand what you're trying to ultimately achieve, but here's a guess at what you might be looking for.
Inactivate[AudioPlay[Audio["ExampleData/rule30.wav"]], AudioPlay]


When you're ready to play/evaluate it, you can use Activate.

So here is an unreliable and hacky way to get my desired output:
Paste[Audio["ExampleData/rule30.wav"]];
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[],After,CellContents];
Paste["//AudioPlay;"];


here is my f:
f[x_] := Module[{},
   
   Paste[x];
   SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, CellContents];
   Paste["//AudioPlay;"];
   ];

I wish I could figure out a more reliable way to do it using Evaluation control functionality https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/EvaluationControl.html
